# How to display content from post_parent

Tags: php, post-content

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I am a beginner coder, but I've tried a lot of things already:

I'm trying to print the_content from the post_parent of an image. Here's what I'm using right now. I am able to post the title, but not the content (all I can succeed in printing content-wise is the image's content (which is actually the image's 'description' which is not what I'm looking for.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'post-image' ); ?>

<h4 class="attach-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

<p>
    <a
        href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>"
        title="<?php esc_attr( printf( __( 'Return to %s', APP_TD ), get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) ) ); ?>"
        rel="gallery">
        <?php
            printf(
                '<span class="meta-nav">' . __( '&larr; Return to %s', APP_TD ) . '</span>',
                get_the_title( $post->post_parent )
            );
        ?>
    </a>
</p>

<p>
    <a
        href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>"
        the_content="<?php esc_attr( printf( __( 'Return to %s', APP_TD ), get_the_content( $post->post_parent ) ) ); ?>"
        rel="gallery">
        <?php
            printf(
                '<span class="meta-nav">' . __( '&larr; Return to %s', APP_TD ) . '</span>',
                get_the_content( $post->post_parent )
            );
        ?>
    </a>
</p>
```

The first 2 pieces of code work correctly, but the last paragraph is where I want to pull the content. But this code just prints the description of the image itself rather than the post_parent's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the other answer, you can not pass an ID to `get_the_content()` function. You could fetch the post using `get_post()`, but there's also another handy function that you can use to fetch the content:

The [`get_post_field( $field, $post_id, $context )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field) function is what you're looking for:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID ) );
```

The `the_content` filter also makes sure that some features like shortcodes or auto-paragraphs will work as intended.

Simply replace your second `<a>...</a>` with this:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->post_parent ) ); ?>
```

Comment: As you can see in your reformatted code, the `the_content` is not a valid attribute for the `<a>` element. But the usage of `get_post_field()` is the same as `get_content()`. You put an `echo` behind it, and it simply echoes the content.

Comment: I think I'm not really understanding what are probably clear instructions due to my noobness. I just get the image description again when I use <?php echo $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID ) ); ?>

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea why the content it prints is not responsive to css-ing? It prints the paragraphs and the gallery (again, which I have to get rid of), but I can't add internal css to display:none the gallery or other items inside the content, or add css to the paragraphs or the gallery thumbnail sizes

Comment: Any element can be affected by CSS, you just have to find the proper selector. Also, you should not wrap this function inside a `<p>` element, because the output is already wrapped in `<p>`, and a paragraph element can't be a child of another paragraph.

Comment: My bad this time. It was a typo, which no code can overcome

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_content()` is a function to be used in the loop and doesn't take a post id as parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

You could try `get_post()` to get the parent post object and then access it's content.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?